# SOAP Message creation without a WebService just with wsdl

Tags: soap, spring-jms

I have a wsdl file in a Spring JMS project, where i need to create an XML to sent to a queue. This xml should look like a SOAP Message including Header Body and whole Envelop. I don't understands how not to implement a SOAP WebService but still create a XML SOAP structure. I don't want to create whole structure using SOAP Element classes where i have to write a lot of code and each time if my Java Object updates i have to update this implementation as well, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Spring Web Services Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/reference/#_jms_transport_2) (specifically JMS Transport on the client side).

> For sending messages over JMS, Spring Web Services provides the `JmsMessageSender`. This class uses the facilities of the Spring framework to transform the `WebServiceMessage` into a JMS Message, send it on its way on a Queue or Topic, and receive a response (if any).
>
> To use the JmsMessageSender, ...

Comment: Thanks but who on server side without any client i push data to JMS queue as there is no request from client, and in SOAP Services client has to request then Server responds even its on JMS or HTTP transport layer.

Comment: I have used wsdl to create ObjectInfo and classes and used SOAP Factories to create manually Envelops and then Header and Body and after creation of complete Envelope, used Translation libs to convert it to Simple XML StringBuffer which is transferred as Byte or Text Message to JMS Queues.